# Calling delegate method from popover class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, delegates

I'm new to Objective C and I'm having trouble getting delegates to work in my code.

I have a class called cViewController and in this class has a UIWebView to fetch webpages and a button above it that calls a popover class called prodMenu. What I'm having trouble with is that the function to call webpages from the prodMenu class and display it on the parent UIWebView isn't working.

**cViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "prodMenu.h"

@interface cViewController : UIViewController <prodMenuDelegate>{
    UIPopoverController *cpopover;
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webImageDisplay;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webImageDisplay;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *cpopover;
- (IBAction)cPopoverTapped:(id)sender;
- (void) fetchWebsite:(NSString *)website; //This is the delegate method I'm trying to call in the popover class.
@end
```

**cViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)cPopoverTapped:(id)sender {
    prodMenu *tp = [[prodMenu alloc] init];
    cpopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tp];
    [tp release];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(40, 0, 50, 50);
    cpopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(250, 225);
    [cpopover presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}

- (void)fetchWebsite:(NSString*)website{ //This function is called by prodMenu class
    NSLog(@"address: %@", website);
    NSString *urlAddress = website;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webImageDisplay loadRequest:requestObj];
    [webImageDisplay release];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self fetchWebsite:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

**prodMenu.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol prodMenuDelegate;

@interface prodMenu : UIViewController{
    <prodMenuDelegate> delegate;
}
- (IBAction)radBtn:(id)sender; //This is the IBAction that calls the fetchWebsite function
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <prodMenuDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol prodMenuDelegate
- (void)fetchWebsite:(NSString *)website;
@end
```

**prodMenu.m**

```
#import "prodMenu.h"
#import "cViewController.h"

@implementation prodMenu
@synthesize delegate;

- (IBAction)radBtn:(id)sender{
    [delegate fetchWebsite:@"http://www.google.com"]; //Here is the call to the method
}
```

Am I missing something here to call the delegate method? There aren't any errors or warnings. All I want to do is when the user presses a button on the popover view, the parent class underneath changes the webpage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your instance of prodMenu ? That is where you would assign the cViewController instance to the 'delegate' property.

Comment: Sorry added the instance of prodMenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick idea. Have you tried declaring the delegate protocol like this

```
@protocol prodMenuDelegate <NSObject>
    ...
@end
```

? I often ran into troubles when omitting the < NSObject >. Also I think there is an 'id' missing in

```
@interface prodMenu : UIViewController{
    <prodMenuDelegate> delegate;
}
```

Edit: Also, in the code you posted I do not see where you actually assign the prodMenu's delegate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was really missing the prodMenu delegate assignment. I just needed the line "tp.delegate = self;" when initiating the cPopoverTapped IBAction. It is working well now, thanks again.